Meaning of "Fisher transformation of cross-correlations"
I am reading a paper which states (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-023-41960-2):

In SUSY the cross-correlations are computed segment-wise; time series are cut into segments of e.g. 30 s duration, and the cross-correlations within each segment are computed across a certain range of lags L. A default value in many studies is choosing maximum lags up to  ± 3 s or ± 5 s, so that all cross-correlations in a 6- or 10-s window, the cross-correlation range L, are considered. Segment-size and window-size are basic parameters in SUSY. This operationalization thus includes the simultaneous (L = 0) correlation as well as time-lagged (cross-)correlations. To allow aggregation, all cross-correlations must be transformed using Fisher’s Z transformation.

I am not sure I understand the jump from cross-correlation to Fisher's Z-transform: isn't Fisher's transform based on the Pearson correlation coefficient? What does it mean to apply Fisher's Z-transform to a cross-correlation? Especially, Fisher's Z transform really only make sense for a value R between -1 and 1 which is not the case of cross-correlation coefficients.

Why aren't cross-correlation coefficients between -1 and 1? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cross_correlation_animation.gif
